# local host not working with Laravel, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED after first time a page is displayed

Tags: php, laravel-5

OK I am new to laravel and when I use "php artisan serve" I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED after the first time a page loads.

The first time there is a large delay of like 9 seconds, even for the default page. However after that first page is displayed, all I get are time outs and Chrome reports ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I have tried in Firefox, Chrome and even IE.

I have tested different server ports, I have tried "php artisan optimize"
I hear that Symfony could be the issue so set the timeout to null there.
I am out of ideas and have no idea what is wrong.

[image: First attempt to access the page]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is help full steps for you.

1. Go to the LAN settings (in Chrome : Tools-> Options-> Under the hood -> Change Proxy setting -> LAN Setting).
2. There will be a check box for "Bypass proxy server for local address".
3. Tick the check box.

Comment: if still not solved.then tell me I have another solution also.

Comment: For all browsers,

->Open internet Options (or Internet properties)
->Go to connections tab
->Click on LAN Settings
->Tick Use proxy server for your LAN
->Tick Bypass proxy server for your local address (Don't change the port number)
->Click on Ok
Now you are good to go. :)

Comment: Sorry for the long wait for reply, have been in class all day. Will try once home (approx 3 hours)